# Rails Validation Error: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm kinda struggling with validations in my Rails application.
I have the following Setup:

```
class MealDay < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :meal 
    belongs_to :day
    has_many :meal_day_canteens
    has_many :canteens,
    through: :meal_day_canteens
    validates :meal_id, uniqueness: {scope: :day_id}
end

#MainController
helping_hash.each { |days, meal|
            dayRef = Day.where(date: days).first
            mealRef = Meal.where(name: meal)
            dayRef.meals << mealRef #This line is obviously throwing the error because a record exists already
}
```

The Error is: "**Validation failed: Meal has already been taken**"
But I'm not sure on how to handle the error. I just want it, so that Rails is not inserting it into the database and skips it. If you need more information just tell me.
Thanks.

Edit: Some more code which I can't get to work now.
Edit2: Forgot to add validation to that model. Works fine now

```
helping_hash.each { |days, meal|
            dayRef = Day.where(date: days).first
            mealRef = Meal.where(name: meal)
            meal_day_ref = MealDay.where(day: dayRef, meal: mealRef)
            @canteenNameRef.meal_days << meal_day_ref rescue next
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `rescue`ing the error?

```
helping_hash.each do |days, meal|
  dayRef = Day.where(date: days).first
  mealRef = Meal.where(name: meal)
  dayRef.meals << mealRef rescue next
end
```

Comment: Hey that work's well for my first part of code but could you take a look at my question again and help me with the part I added. Thanks.

Comment: That it gets inserted multiple times.

Comment: Do you have validation in thay model too?

Comment: I just figured that too -.-. I forgot to add a validation to that model. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Great..btw, that's a hacky solution..since it `rescue`s all the exceptions..not recommended but useful if you know what you are doing. Take a note of that..

Answer (score 0):

Rails uniqueness constraint is basically throwing a query under the hood to look for a record in the DB. More of a side comment but this is already not safe concurrently so I recommend you adding a constraint at the database level.

You basically need to do the manual work of skipping the ones that already exist.

Basically something like:

```
helping_hash.each do |day, meal|
  day_ref = Day.find_by!(date: day)
  meal_ref = Meal.find_by!(name: meal)
  unless day_ref.meal_ids.include?(meal_ref.id)
    # Depending on the number of records you expect
    # using day_ref.meals.exists?(id: meal_ref.id) may be a better choice
    day_ref.meals << meal_ref
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it's not working how I wan't it. Can I define another condition for the exists or include function? Because I don't wan't to insert it if the pair of meal and day are already in the database. Basically a constraint for (meal_id, day_id). I guess that was not really clear from my question.